# AWS EC2 - Amazon Linux AMI - PHP script not working (Slim Framework)

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, slim

I've been bashing my head over and over attempting to sort out the problem with my PHP code, but to no avail.

I'm trying to allow the user to download the .xml/.json file created from my code but it keeps destroying my page, leaving a blank, whitespace.

Can anyone have a look and let me know where the problem is?

```
<FORM action="MYSITE.PHP" method="get">
<BR />URL To Search: 
<INPUT type="text" name="URL" value="$requested_url"> <BR />
Feedback type to receive: 
<SELECT name="Feedback">
<OPTION name="">Please Select...</OPTION>
<OPTION name="XML">XML</OPTION>
<OPTION name="JSON">JSON</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<BR /><BR />
 <INPUT type="submit" value="Check this website">
<P style="color:blue">$returned</P>
<P>$link_count item(s) found</P>
</FORM>
</DIV>
<DIV style="margin-right:5px; padding-left:5px; width:49%; float:right">
HTMLDATA;

if ($feedbackValue != "") {
 $data = array("Main URL" => $requested_url, "Sub URLs" => $returned_array);
 if ($feedbackValue == "JSON") {
  $output = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data));
  $handler = fopen("output.json", "wb") or die('Can\'t open file');
  fwrite($handler, $output);
  fclose($handler);
 }
 else if ($feedbackValue == "XML")
 {
  $output = htmlspecialchars(xmlrpc_encode($data));
  $handler = fopen("output.xml", "wb") or die('Can\'t open file');
  fwrite($handler, $output);
  fclose($handler);
 }
 $result = <<<HTMLDATA4
 <FORM action="MYSITEOTHER.php" method="get">
 <INPUT type="hidden" name="Feedback" value="$feedbackValue" />
 <INPUT type="submit" value="Download File" />
 </FORM>
 HTMLDATA4;
```

**EDIT:**
I've got a funny feeling it's fopen, as the code won't even open a file. (JSON and XML-RPC are both enabled)

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have. There's nothing there

Comment: @JayBlanchard Geez, it's 177 lines of code, do you _really_ want that as code up on SO?

Comment: If PasteBin ever goes offline it will make your question (and potential answers) worthless.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'll add the offending code only then, and I'll work on the full code later. At work and about to go home

Comment: Do you have JSON enabled in PHP... Do you have RPC enabled in PHP... plz check your php config. Not all PHP is compiled with either of these.

Comment: @geggleto the JSON/RPC is just some PHP code, which should automatically be installed when I installed LAMP

Comment: @Raisus that is not the case.

Comment: @geggleto Oh? Didn't know that. I'll check when I get back tomorrow

Comment: @geggleto They're already enabled. I've just checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had already installed php 5.6 and xmlrpc, but I didn't realize that every time I tried to yum install php-xmlrpc, it kept giving me conflict errors, but it was trying to install PHP v5.5 xmlrpc onto my 5.6 version.

So all I had to do to fix the issue was type the following code into my linux box:

```
sudo yum install -y php56-xmlrpc
```

Comment: @geggleto The odd thing was, xmlrpc was already installed by default through LAMP, just the wrong version, hence the conflict errors.
BUT, thank you, anyway